# Running shell commands on the click of a button

Tags: android, shell, adb, root-access

I wish to reset an android device programmatically using :
`adb shell
recovery --wipe_data`

## 1. What is the easiest way to do this ?

## 2. Will it require root/superuser access ?

Answer (score 0):

For running shell commands you can use `Runtime` class. For more information check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html)

For example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("commands_here");
```

Comment: Can I run it from `OnCreate` itself ?